facing a "Create Account: account Address already in use" when running TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method
Hi I am facing a "Create Account: account Address { address: xxx, base: None } already in use" when running TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method which is associated to package @solana/spl-token-swap.
The main error is telling me that token swap account is already existing,
'Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use',

Based on this error the TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method requires a new token swap account. I cannot (I tried) to create a new keypair specifically for the TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method despite it not making sense.  It gave me a wrong account error, as expected. The token swap account that I am using inside the TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method is required to create the authority and pooltoken account that the same method also requires in the first place, so it cannot be a new account.
This is the full error message below which you can see the successful log of token swap account being created earlier then error occurring at TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method, complaining that the token swap account already exists.
yarn run v1.22.22
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register scripts/tokenswap_test.ts
Starting the token swap process...
Connected to Solana devnet
Loaded keypair from file
Created new payer with public key: 95965cvdezF21uqiSGnYC1nwX392a19wjLBWpAxnYiSR
Transferring 0.1 SOL to payer...
Transferred 0.1 SOL to 95965cvdezF21uqiSGnYC1nwX392a19wjLBWpAxnYiSR
Transaction signature: 3SB6WhDpi6LGnvuJBpfgnSUfYUVdaT5qfZ9VVY6SPcvn3trYMWJPr3AGsNdgVj26MyRGQ2Jue4ZCPGZdM3WhsfN6
Minting tokens...
Tokens minted to accounts
Creating token swap account...
Token swap account created: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp
Initializing token swap...
SendTransactionError occurred:
Error message: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
Error logs: [
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
  'Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0'
]
Detailed error logs:
Log 1: Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
Log 2: Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use
Log 3: Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0
An error occurred:
SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/yu/solana_proj/pirate-bootcamp-main/quest-1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:6043:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/yu/solana_proj/pirate-bootcamp-main/quest-1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5999:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/home/yu/solana_proj/pirate-bootcamp-main/quest-1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5987:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/home/yu/solana_proj/pirate-bootcamp-main/quest-1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:36:21) {
  signature: '',
  transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Create Account: account Address { address: CiJauS3ipqsvyc2VLwibqHzu5ga3rUg69xhYfPs2dsRp, base: None } already in use',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0'
  ]
}
Done in 14.62s.

FYI, I was referring to https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-swap/js/src/index.ts for the TokenSwap.createTokenSwap method.
And this is my code for easy replication of the error. and these are the packages involved - "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.8", "@solana/spl-token-swap": "^0.4.3", "@solana/web3.js": "^1.95.3"
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  SendTransactionError
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
  TokenSwap,
  CurveType,
} from '@solana/spl-token-swap';
import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  createMint,
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  approve,
  getAccount
} from '@solana/spl-token';
import fs from 'fs';

async function main() {
  console.log("Starting the token swap process...");

  const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', 'confirmed');
  console.log("Connected to Solana devnet");

  const secretKeyString = fs.readFileSync('/home/yu/.config/solana/id.json', 'utf8');
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
  const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
  console.log("Loaded keypair from file");
  const AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER = 0.1;

  const payer = Keypair.generate();
  console.log(`Created new payer with public key: ${payer.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

  const useAirdrop = true; // Set this to false to use transfer instead of airdrop

  if (useAirdrop) {
    console.log(`Airdropping ${AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER} SOL to payer...`);
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      payer.publicKey,
      AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    console.log(`Airdropped ${AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER} SOL to ${payer.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
    console.log(`Airdrop signature: ${airdropSignature}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Transferring ${AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER} SOL to payer...`);
    const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: fromWallet.publicKey,
      toPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      lamports: AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    });

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [fromWallet]);
    console.log(`Transferred ${AMOUNT_TO_TRANSFER} SOL to ${payer.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
    console.log(`Transaction signature: ${signature}`);
  }

  const mintA = await createMint(connection, payer, payer.publicKey, payer.publicKey, 9);
  const mintB = await createMint(connection, payer, payer.publicKey, payer.publicKey, 9);

  const tokenAccountA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, payer, mintA, payer.publicKey);
  const tokenAccountB = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, payer, mintB, payer.publicKey);

  console.log("Minting tokens...");
  await mintTo(connection, payer, mintA, tokenAccountA.address, payer, 1000000000);
  await mintTo(connection, payer, mintB, tokenAccountB.address, payer, 1000000000);
  console.log("Tokens minted to accounts");

  console.log("Creating token swap account...");
  const tokenSwapAccount = Keypair.generate();
  const TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey('SwaPpA9LAaLfeLi3a68M4DjnLqgtticKg6CnyNwgAC8');
  const TOKENSWAPLAYOUTSPAN = 324;
  const rent = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(TOKENSWAPLAYOUTSPAN);
  const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: tokenSwapAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: rent,
    space: TOKENSWAPLAYOUTSPAN,
    programId: TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  });

  const createSwapAccountTransaction = new Transaction().add(createAccountInstruction);
  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createSwapAccountTransaction, [payer, tokenSwapAccount]);
  console.log(`Token swap account created: ${tokenSwapAccount.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

  const [authority, bumpSeed] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [tokenSwapAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const poolToken = await createMint(connection, payer, authority, null, 9);
  const poolTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, payer, poolToken, payer.publicKey);
  const feeAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, payer, poolToken, payer.publicKey);

  console.log("Initializing token swap...");
  try {
    const tokenSwap = await TokenSwap.createTokenSwap(
      connection,
      payer,
      tokenSwapAccount,
      authority,
      tokenAccountA.address,
      tokenAccountB.address,
      poolToken,
      mintA,
      mintB,
      feeAccount.address,
      poolTokenAccount.address,
      TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      0n,  // tradeFeeNumerator
      10000n,  // tradeFeeDenominator
      0n,  // ownerTradeFeeNumerator
      0n,  // ownerTradeFeeDenominator
      0n,  // ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator
      0n,  // ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator
      20n,  // hostFeeNumerator
      100n,  // hostFeeDenominator
      CurveType.ConstantProduct
    );
    console.log('Token swap initialized successfully');

    console.log("Loading TokenSwap instance...");
    const tokenSwapInstance = await TokenSwap.loadTokenSwap(
      connection,
      tokenSwapAccount.publicKey,
      TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
      payer
    );
    console.log("TokenSwap instance loaded");

    const userTransferAuthority = Keypair.generate();
    console.log(`User transfer authority created: ${userTransferAuthority.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

    const swapAmount = 10000000;

    console.log("Approving transfer...");
    await approve(
      connection,
      payer,
      tokenAccountA.address,
      userTransferAuthority.publicKey,
      payer,
      swapAmount
    );
    console.log("Transfer approved");

    console.log("Performing swap...");
    await tokenSwapInstance.swap(
      tokenAccountA.address,
      tokenAccountA.address,
      tokenAccountB.address,
      tokenAccountB.address,
      mintA,
      mintB,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      feeAccount.address,
      userTransferAuthority,
      BigInt(swapAmount),
      BigInt(0)
    );

    console.log('Swap completed');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof SendTransactionError) {
      console.error('SendTransactionError occurred:');
      console.error('Error message:', error.message);
      console.error('Error logs:', error.logs);
      if (error.logs) {
        console.error('Detailed error logs:');
        error.logs.forEach((log, index) => {
          console.error(`Log ${index + 1}:`, log);
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.error('An unexpected error occurred:', error);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("An error occurred:");
  console.error(err);
});




The createTokenSwap method will create the account on the inside: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d5844633b194bed5f53f4f1d1ec650370cd0e279/token-swap/js/src/index.ts#L413
So if you remove the call to createAccount on the token swap account, this will be correct. Feel free to reuse some of the tests! Like https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d5844633b194bed5f53f4f1d1ec650370cd0e279/token-swap/js/test/main.test.ts#L131
